# nginx serving multiple wordpress sites showing 403 forbidden

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have nginx configured with multiple configurations in /etc/nginx/conf.d to serve multiple Wordpress sites. Each config follows this structure:

```
upstream my-site-php-handler {
        server unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
}

server {
        listen 80;

        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        root /var/www/my-site;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass my-site-php-handler;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

All requests to the site result in a 403 forbidden. That is until I remove `$uri/` from the try_files in location /.

I believe `$uri/` is required for wp-admin to work, as when I remove this I get too many redirects. The wp-admin directory is configured with the same permissions as everything else in the site directory for now, and everything else works with the `$uri/` removed. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should add that if I remove the $uri/ and browse to url/wp-admin/index.php, it works. It's just browsing to wp-admin which doesn't

Comment: The error log should give you the reason, and its probably "directory index is forbidden". You are missing an `index index.php;` or `index index.html index.php;`statement to tell Nginx that you are using PHP indexes.

Comment: @RichardSmith I used the recipe provided at https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/ and this fixed the issue. The major difference I saw between this and what I'd configured was the inclusion of `index index.php` - so this was likely the solution